# Why is IDependencyResolver tightly coupled with System.Web?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Why is the reason the `IDependencyResolver` is coupled with the `System.Web` assembly (either `Mvc` or `Http`) in the .NET framework ?

The goal of a DI system isn't that it should provide an agnostic way of serving dependencies to a customer ? What if I want to use `IDependencyResolver` in a project **that should not reference anything related to System.Web** ?

**Edit:**
This is more a philosophical question than a request about how to do, because I know there are other alternatives such as open source DI library.

Comment: It is an interface that says It is not tightly coupled. Either you can use built in dependency resolver which are available in .net or you can write you own by implementing `IDependencyResolver` interface.  If you use castle Windsor or Unity or Ninject which are already having their own version of this resolver.

Comment: There is the IServiceProvider interface that is part of System.  However, it is a pretty limited interface

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The goal of a DI system isn't that it should provide an agnostic way of serving dependencies to a customer ?

That is correct, but in this case, `IDependencyResolver` is specific to the library where it is defined. It is that library's DI abstraction to allow an agnostic extensibitliy point for dependency resolution. And I believe that that was the initial goal of the abstraction.

It was not really made to be reused independently by other libraries, which is evident in that there are two versions for both [MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.idependencyresolver(v=vs.118).aspx) and [Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.dependencies.idependencyresolver(v=vs.118).aspx). Though they share the same name and have the same purpose, their implementations differ slightly.

It also demonstrates the [Conforming Container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/conforming-container/) anti-pattern as mentioned in this article by Mark Seemann, where the article also mentions the above abstractions as known examples of Conforming Containers for .NET. Even my preferred approach of using `IServiceProvider` made the list.

> What if I want to use `IDependencyResolver` in a project that should
>   not reference anything related to System.Web ?

My suggestion then would be to not use `IDependencyResolver` from *System.Web*. I would also add that above all, particular attention should be payed to following proper design patterns, making sure that one has an understanding of the concepts and where they should be applied or avoided.

Comment: Excellent answer, nevertheless i still wonder why `IServiceProvider` was not reused in `System.Web` in place of `IDependencyResolver` ?

Comment: That is a question for the designers of that system. However, they have reverted back to `IServiceProvider` in the following version which is what we have today in asp.net-core. That was to do away with the same tight coupling that plagued System.Web.

Comment: I recommend to read the following articles: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/conforming-container/

https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2016/06/whats-wrong-with-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit I have read that article multiple times before setting on my current design. It is an interesting read. My take from it though was that if everything is confined to the composition root then that argument is somewhat moot. I do appreciate your reference  to that said article.

Comment: @Nkosi I agree, having a proper composition root counteracts the downsides. Not being able to use specific containers features is a downside that should be carefully weighed against being able to swap out a container easily. Personally, I've never had to swap out a container. But I know of others who had to. Question of course is what's more expensive: maintaining an abstraction that *might* be used or biting the bullet when a change is necessary. Personally I follow YAGNI.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit I will see how I can incorporate what we discussed into the the answer. Thanks again for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit I see your point and I do not. The basic idea behind allowing the replacement of service provider is to let library users extend the current behavior. They use their own containers, extenders, factories and just give us - the framework authors the objects we need. In other - even more abstract - words, we let library users proxy our objects. ;)

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/ that is a fitting read from same source.

Answer (score 2):

The interface `IDependencyResolver` is an extension point of the System.Web-frameworks. The frameworks rely on this interface to resolve instances (of controllers and their like) and their dependencies.

The framework has its own implementation of the interface, but you can provide your own implementation of this interface. The Built-in implementation has a limited functionality (external configuration, injection types, interception).

Most IOC-Container and DI-Frameworks provide an implementation of this interface, so that you can integrate them into the existing framework.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the reason the IDependencyResolver is coupled with the
>   System.Web assembly (either Mvc or Http) in the .NET framework ?

Because it is an interface 'they' use to resolve framework services. But yeah... they should, for the very least, have used `IServiceProvider` from `System` namespace.

> The goal of a DI system isn't that it should provide an agnostic way of 
>   serving dependencies to a customer ?

Nope. That is not the goal in that context. The main goal for framework author is to let you extend or even replace internal services framework is using.

In your code you should introduce your own facades over these 'standard' interfaces. They are very weak abstractions - good for base, but very far away from any richer resolving or lifetime management strategies.

> What if I want to use IDependencyResolver in a project that should not 
>   reference anything related to System.Web ?

You cannot (without adding `System.Web` reference) and you shouldn't. Use your own internal abstraction(Facade) over DI framework. Just like you shouldn't use `NLog.ILogger` directly in your classes, same applies to DI framework abstractions.

Some frameworks will make it close to or just impossible to do but you should use your own Facades wherever possible.

Same rules apply in broader sense as well.
Don't attach your project (unnecessarily) to some cloud service such as Azure. Other side might have much better prices some day. Limit dependencies and sticky parts as much as possible.

> Edit:
>   This is more a philosophical question than a request about how to do, 
>   because I know there are other alternatives such as open source DI library.

Oh... and same advice go with DI frameworks. Don't overuse DI framework features that could be easily implemented in different way over your Facades.

NOTE: Same goes with: CI pipelines, Service Bus/Message Queue frameworks.